# Cancel $animate.leave removing element from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-animate

If [`$animate.leave`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/service/$animate#leave) has been called on an element, to remove it from the DOM after a delay/animation, how can this animation be cancelled so that the element remains in the DOM?

Note that calling [`$animate.cancel`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/service/$animate#cancel) on the promise returned from `$animate.leave` doesn't achieve this. It actually immediately removes the element from the DOM, rather than preventing it from leaving.

Below is an example directive with a js-based animation

```
app.directive('removeOnClick', function($animate) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var promise = null;
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          if (!promise) {
            promise = $animate.leave(element);
            promise.then(function() {
              promise = null;
            });
          } else {
            // This seems to remove the element from the DOM immediately
            $animate.cancel(promise);
            promise = null;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
});

app.animation('.my-button', function($window) {
  return {
    leave: function(element, done) {
      $window.setTimeout(done, 2000);
    }
  };
});
```

The above can be seen in-action at http://plnkr.co/edit/KVtSFJTRhw3Ks7tomqDQ?p=preview